# Memory management across threads

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

The module i am working on consists of a couple of threads(similar to a producer/consumer), the messaging between them is done through sending the produced object's address through the boost::message_queue send function.

Till now, the memory management was done explicitly through instantiating the object in producer thread and deleting it in the consumer thread after it's usage.

Now, I am planning to remove this explicit management with self managed memory (smart pointer / boost shared_ptr) for obvious reasons (controlling complexity and avoiding leaks).

The one issue i am facing is that the boost::message_queue send/receive api uses raw pointer in it's signature and i want the memory to be shared across threads. So how do i manage the reference counting, so that message object doesn't get destroyed immediately after the scope of producer thread function is over, but even before the consumer thread has finished its task ?

One way is to get the shared_ptr serialized and use it for passing in between the threads.
Is there any more obvious way that I am missing? It would be great if i could get more alternatives here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

boost::message_queue is more suited for inter-**process** communication. If you just want to do inter-**thread** message passing, I'd rather use a simple queue (with suitable synchronization) holding your shared_pointers.

Comment: In particular, for alternatives, I would advise taking a look at TBB: Intel's Thread Building Blocks library.

Answer (score 0):

The [boost::interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) is particularly suited to your needs as it is [compatible with the boost::smart_ptr library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp). Here is the summary:

> Boost.Interprocess simplifies the use of common interprocess
>   communication and synchronization mechanisms and offers a wide range
>   of them:
>
> 1. Shared memory.
> 2. Memory-mapped files.
> 3. Semaphores, mutexes, condition variables and upgradable mutex types
>      to place them in shared memory and memory mapped files.
> 4. Named versions of those synchronization objects, similar to
>      UNIX/Windows sem_open/CreateSemaphore API.
> 5. File locking.
> 6. Relative pointers.
> 7. Message queues.

The semaphore capabilities seem adequate as you stated that

> The module I am working on consists of a couple of threads(similar to a producer/consumer), the
>   messaging between